# Discord.js - TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'commands')

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm coding a Discord Bot in JavaScript, but I have this error when I launch the bot !
I don't find because I check the "application.commands" box!
Here's the full error message:

I don't know how I can resolve the problem :(

I try to invite my bot another time, but it doesn't work :(

The error message who makes problems :

```
node:events:491
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'commands')
    at Client.<anonymous> (/home/container/index.js:72:51)
    at Client.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at WebSocketManager.triggerClientReady (/home/container/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketManager.js:385:17)
    at WebSocketManager.checkShardsReady (/home/container/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketManager.js:368:10)
    at WebSocketShard.<anonymous> (/home/container/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketManager.js:194:14)
    at WebSocketShard.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at WebSocketShard.checkReady (/home/container/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketShard.js:511:12)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (/home/container/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketShard.js:483:16)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (/home/container/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketShard.js:320:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (/home/container/node_modules/ws/lib/event-target.js:199:18)
Emitted 'error' event on Client instance at:
    at emitUnhandledRejectionOrErr (node:events:394:10)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:84:21)
Node.js v18.12.0
```

The default code :

```
const { Client, GatewayIntentBits, Message, version, MessageFlags } = require("discord.js");
const { SlashCommandBuilder} = require("@discordjs/builders");
const { EmbedBuilder } = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client({
    intents: [
        GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages
    ]
})



//const { REST, Routes } = require('discord.js');
const {clientId, skorflexID, guildId, token, hostRole, multiplayerAnnouncementRole, fortniteLogo, rebootLogo,  basicFortniteImage, sept, un, quatre, trois, modoID } = require('./config.json');


const announce = new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName("announce")
    .setDescription("This command will send a embed message to announce your hosting !")

    .addStringOption(option => option
        .setName("version")
        .setDescription("Put the version of Fortnite you want to host")
        .setRequired(true))
    .addStringOption(option => option
        .setName("radmin_ip")
        .setDescription("Put your Radmin IP here (without the 'open')")
        .setRequired(true));


const clear = new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName("clear")
    .setDescription("This command will delete a number of messages in one second !")
    
    .addIntegerOption(option => option
        .setName("number")
        .setDescription("Put the number of messages who will be deleted !")
        .setRequired(true))


const say = new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName("say")
    .setDescription("The bot will say your message")

    .addStringOption(option => option
        .setName("message")
        .setDescription("Type your message !")
        .setRequired(true))


const thumbnail = new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName("thumbnail")
    .setDescription("The bot send you the thumbnail of a YouTube video")

    .addStringOption(option => option
        .setName("id")
        .setDescription("You can find the ID in the link after the << watch?v= >>")
        .setRequired(true))

    


client.on("ready", async () => {
    client.guilds.cache.get("1027595307187441664").commands.create(thumbnail);
    client.guilds.cache.get(guildId).commands.fetch();

    client.guilds.cache.get(guildId).commands.cache.map(command => {
        command.delete();
    });

    console.log("Le bot est lancé et prêt à l'utilisation !");
});



client.on("interactionCreate", interaction => {
    
    if(interaction.isCommand()){
        // announce ou announcement
        if(interaction.commandName === "announce" || interaction.commandName === "announcement"){
            let version1 = interaction.options.getString("version")
            let radmin_ip1 = interaction.options.getString("radmin_ip")
            let image = basicFortniteImage;

            if( version1 != undefined && radmin_ip1 != undefined ){

                if(version1 ==="7.30" || version1 ==="7.3" || version1 ==="7.2"|| version1 ==="7.1"|| version1 ==="7"){
                    image = sept;
                }else if(version1 == "1.7.2"){
                    image = un;
                }else if(version1 =="3.5"){
                    image = trois;
                }else if(version1 =="4.5"){
                    image = quatre;
                }

                const exampleEmbed = new EmbedBuilder()
                    .setColor(0xFFA3F8)
                    .setTitle("**Multiplayer Announcement**")
                    .setDescription("<@"+interaction.user.id+"> is hosting rn in **"+ version1 + "**\n\n - To join, write this in the fortnite console : \n\n> `open "+ radmin_ip1 +"`\n\n To open the fortnite console you need to press the ² button or if it's doesn't work press ` ")
                    .setImage(image)
                    .setFooter({ text: 'Hosted with Reboot Launcher', iconURL: rebootLogo})
                    .setThumbnail(fortniteLogo)
                    .setTimestamp()
                    .setFields({name: "To join", value: 'you need to be connected on **RADMIN VPN**'})
                
                if(interaction.member.roles.cache.some(e => e.id == hostRole)){
                    interaction.channel.send("<@&"+multiplayerAnnouncementRole+">")
                    interaction.reply({embeds: [exampleEmbed]});
                }else{
                    interaction.reply({ content: "You don't have the Host role !", ephemeral: true });
                }
            }
        }

        if(interaction.commandName === "clear"){
            var number = interaction.options.getInteger("number")
            if(interaction.member.roles.cache.some(e => e.id == modoID)){
                if(number >= 1 && number <= 100){
                    interaction.channel.bulkDelete(number);
                    interaction.reply({content: number + " messages has been deleted correctly !", ephemeral: true});
                }else{
                    interaction.reply({content: "To use the clear command, your number will be over 1 and under 100 ! Please retry", ephemeral: true});
                }
            }
        }
        
        if(interaction.commandName === "say"){
            let message2 = interaction.options.getString("message");
            
            
            if(interaction.member.roles.cache.some(e => e.id == modoID)){
                interaction.reply({content: "."})
                interaction.deleteReply();
                interaction.channel.send({content: message2})
            }else if(interaction.member.roles.cache.some(i => i.id != modoID)){
                interaction.reply({content: "You are not a moderator !", ephemeral: true})
            }
            
        }
        if(interaction.commandName === "thumbnail"){
            var ytID = interaction.options.getString("id");
            
            interaction.reply({content: "."})
            interaction.deleteReply();
            interaction.channel.send({content: "https://img.youtube.com/vi/"+ ytID +"/maxresdefault.jpg"})

        }

    }
})


client.login(token);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's referring to this line here:

```
client.guilds.cache.get("1027595307187441664").commands.create(thumbnail);
```

Basically `client.guilds.cache.get("1027595307187441664")` is undefined and did not return a result.